# Using several cache-manifest files

Tags: html, caching, web-applications

I a have developed a web-application which supports offline-version as well. I have modified it, so that I can present on the browser ony a particular interface (Screen) of the application by passing the according url. For example the whole application is presented under the url:

```
http: //project
```

A particular Screen can be shown under an Url like:

```
http: //project/anything/screenid/anything
```

My question is how can I provide offline-capability also for the individual Screens. Since the application stores by default in the `cache-manifest` file only the resources loaded the last time the application run, it cannot keep the right module-Screen for each Url. Is there any way to link each Url to a separate `cache_manifest` file in order to support offline-version for each individual Screen?